# How can I define a parameter in Dockerfile dynamically and pass it to next step?

Tags: python, bash, docker, dockerfile

I want:

step 1. Get the running Python Version in Docker image

step 2. Find the different paths of Python Env

step 3. *export* all of them

Because I know where one of the Python paths is so my current solution in Dockerfile is:

```
ENV PYTHONPATH "${PYTHONPATH}:THE_PATH_TO/pyvenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages"
```

It is working but not dynamic and not pretty.

I tried the following script.

```
RUN \
  # read the python version
  PYVER=$(python3 -c 'import sys; print(str(sys.version_info[0])+"."+str(sys.version_info[1]))'); \
  
  # possible path to python env
  for DEP_PY_PATH in $(find UNDER_A_FOLDER -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d); do \

    if [ -d "${DEP_PY_PATH}/pyvenv/lib/python${PYVER}/site-packages" ]; then \
    PYTHONPATH=${PYTHONPATH}:${DEP_PY_PATH}/pyvenv/lib/python${PYVER}/site-packages; \
    fi; \

  done 

ENV PYTHONPATH "${PYTHONPATH}"
```

No Error and also not working.

Comment: ```which python``` or ```which python3``` will give you python/python3 path. But I did not understand how you want to use it later .

Comment: Hello, because I need the python version to put into the path like /pyvenv/lib/python${PYTHON_VERSION}/site-packages, then it will look like /pyvenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages

Comment: You shouldn't need to do any of this.  It's fine to use `pip` to install "system" packages in a Docker image, since it's isolated from any other Docker image or Python installation.  Then these packages will be in the normal `$PYTHONPATH`, and you don't need to do any special configuration.

Comment: I fixed it in a dirty way as a temporary solution, I moved all the dependencies under the system python path. The case can be closed.